# How to fix COM outproc server initializing error 0x80004015?

Tags: com, atl

I have a COM outproc server written in ATL that registers itself using

```
_Module.RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_SINGLEUSE)
```

and it results in an HRESULT error code 0x80004015 (which means CO_E_WRONG_SERVER_IDENTITY). What causes this error code, and how can I work around this error?

Comment: I have just discovered that the presence of the `LocalServer` value in the AppID registry key for the application caused this error code to be returned by `CoResumeClassObjects` in our ATL server program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any specific DCOM permissions set on the server? Alternatively, check the identity of the caller that causes the server process to be launched against the default DCOM permissions. It might be that the caller is service running under particular account and the process is launched as Interactive User.

Here's [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169321) with more info that can help you figure out the problem.

Comment: It seems the DCOM settings for this outproc server was set to be an Interactive User. Reverting to "the launching user" fixed the registration. Thanks!